# How to generate SSL using a batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, ssl

**What i am trying to accomplish**

I want to create and install a pfx certificate using a batch file

```
@echo off
cls

set exepath=C:\OpenSSL\bin\openssl.exe

%exepath% genrsa -out "%1".key %2
%exepath% req -new -key "%1".key -out "%1".csr -config %OPENSSL_CONF%
%exepath% x509 -req -days %3 -in "%1".csr -signkey "%1".key -out "%1".crt

//code causing the error
%exepath% pkcs12 -export -in "%1".crt -inkey "%1".key -out ""_pkcs12.pfx -
name "Universe Self-Signed SSL" 

del "%1.key"
del "%1.csr"
```

**Expected Result**
I am expecting a pfx file generates and installed

**Actual Result**

What i am actually getting is

Error opening input file .crt
.crt: No such file or directory
;

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: @jww: The question is about CMD/batch syntax.  CMD/batch, while idiosyncratic and limited, is still generally considered programming.  Additionally, it is Windows-only, not Unix/Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mixing quoted and unquoted strings in a single parameter, while in theory legal, is likely to confuse some software.  You can also put in some sanity checks to make sure things exist.  Try the below.  If it still fails, copy-and-paste and post the exact terminal/console window output, so we can see what went wrong.

```
@echo off
cls

set exepath=C:\OpenSSL\bin\openssl.exe

%exepath% genrsa -out "%1.key" %2
IF NOT EXIST "%1.key" (
    ECHO genera failed to produce output
    EXIT /B
    )

%exepath% req -new -key "%1.key" -out "%1.csr" -config %OPENSSL_CONF%
IF NOT EXIST "%1.csr" (
    ECHO req failed to produce output
    EXIT /B
    )

%exepath% x509 -req -days %3 -in "%1.csr" -signkey "%1.key" -out "%1.crt"
IF NOT EXIST "%1.crt" (
    ECHO x509 failed to produce output
    EXIT /B
    )

%exepath% pkcs12 -export -in "%1".crt -inkey "%1".key -out "%1_pkcs12.pfx" -name "Universe Self-Signed SSL"
IF NOT EXIST "%1_pkcs12.pfx" (
    ECHO pkcs12 failed to produce output
    EXIT /B
    )

del "%1.key"
del "%1.csr"
```

Comment: @StephenMooney - I am glad it worked for you.  If you consider your question resolved, please [accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: Where I can see whether it installed or not, I got only .key file with private key but i need appid and certhash also.